# Rethinkdb and python driver-unable to connect

Tags: python, rethinkdb

Im having a problem with connecting to my RethinkDB local host using my python driver.
The directory structure is:

**home/rethinkdb/drivers/python.**

When Im inside this python directory I start the python shell.
I type 
    import rethinkdb as r
    r.connect('localhost', 28015).repl()

I get the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "rethinkdb/net.py", line 366, in connect
        return Connection(host, port, db, auth_key, timeout)
  File "rethinkdb/net.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.reconnect(noreply_wait=False)
  File "rethinkdb/net.py", line 157, in reconnect
    self._sock_sendall(struct.pack("<L", p.VersionDummy.Protocol.JSON))
  File "rethinkdb/net.py", line 219, in _sock_sendall
    return self.socket.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
**socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe**
```

I have no idea why this occurs-Help appreciated!

Comment: And driver and Rethinkdb version is?

Comment: @janihh Rethinkdb's version is 1.12.5...Im not sure how I would check the version of the driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to connect:

```
r.connect(host="localhost", port=28015).repl()
```

And make sure that the server and the driver has a matching version (at least the first two numbers).

```
rethinkdb --version
pip freeze | grep rethinkdb
```

If they don't, update the server/driver.

Comment: Check the version of your driver/server, that's probably the problem.

Comment: @ neumino..Rethinkdb server version is 1.12 while the driver is 1.15.
How would I downgrade the driver version?

Comment: With something like that I believe: `pip2 install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-1.12.0-2.tar.gz --user`

Comment: @neumino..Thanks for that-all the connections worked fine now!...On a related note:Do you know how I would access an already existing table on rethinkdb form the python driver?...I can create new table but Im unable to access a table that was already existing(Im only able to do it via the data explorer tab)

Comment: When I do an r.connect do I need to explicitly specify the db name I need to use?

Comment: Nop by default it's `test`. And you can overwrite it with `r.db("foo").table("bar")`.