# Unable to connect rethinkdb using Python

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I am trying to connect with Rethinkdb using Python. I sucessfully installed rethinkdb using
pip install rethinkdb on ubuntu. but I try to connect rethinkdb using python as follows:

```
import rethinkdb as r
conn=r.connect().repl()
```

I am getting the following error on connection:

```
ethinkdb.errors.ReqlDriverError: Could not connect to localhost:28015. Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209185/rethinkdb-and-python-driver-unable-to-connect) I found that this issue arises if we have different rethinkdb driver version and server version. I am able to find rethinkdb version
using

```
pip freeze
```

It gives following:

```
backports-abc==0.5
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
bleach==2.1.2
boto==2.38.0
cassandra-driver==3.12.0
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==2.3.0
click==6.7
configparser==3.5.0
cryptography==1.2.3
decorator==4.1.2
duplicity==0.7.6
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.2
Flask==0.12.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
futures==3.2.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.0
ipaddress==1.0.16
ipykernel==4.7.0
ipython==5.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.0.5
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.0
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
lockfile==0.12.2
MarkupSafe==1.0
mistune==0.8.3
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0
notebook==5.2.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
pathlib2==2.3.0
pexpect==4.3.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
ptyprocess==0.5.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
Pygments==2.2.0
pygobject==3.20.0
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
python-cloudfiles==1.7.10
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pyxdg==0.25
pyzmq==16.0.3
qtconsole==4.3.1
requests==2.9.1
rethinkdb==2.3.0.post6
scandir==1.6
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.3.1
tornado==4.5.2
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.13.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
widgetsnbextension==3.0.8
```

Rethinkdb version is there, But I don't know how to check server version. Please help me with this.

After starting virtualenv, when I tried to start rethinkdb it gives error. 
As in following screenshot. [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your server running?. Can you show the result of the executing the following command in the terminal?.

```
ps aux | grep rethinkdb
```

Comment: It gives the following:     khurram   3386  0.0  1.8 576796 38820 tty2     Sl+  15:56   0:01 gedit /home/khurram/work/flask/rethinkdbexport.py
khurram   3680  0.0  0.0  14228  1032 pts/0    S+   17:30   0:00 grep --color=auto rethinkdb

Comment: seems only your python file and the terminal command is working. I cannot see any running server information. Have you started the server manually?. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-rethinkdb-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Comment: I started virtualenv and when I tried to run " rethinkdb --bind all " , it gives error " rethinkdb: command not found". Please see the screenshot I added in the original question above.

Comment: You were right server was not installed, we need to install rethinkdb server prior to the driver installation. I followed the instruction using following link and installed server and it resolved the issue.  https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/